# What is the history between Nina Sharp and Phillip Broyles?

Tags: fringe, romantic-interest

We see hints of the relationship between Nina and Broyles throughout the show. Broyles seems to trust her during the first season even with evidence of her involvement with ZFT.  Also there is the kiss on the steps.  Do we get any direct references to their history?
Was this a plot thread that just never was explored?  Is there any commentary from the creators on this?

Comment: Romantic history, or just general relationship?

Comment: Anything solid on either, there seems to be a wistfulness in the time they kissed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in the production providing details on their history.  They have clearly been involved professionally for a long time.  In all universes there are hints of hidden conspiracies involving secrets that are not shared in the production.

Just another plot thread that was never fully explored.